# Suptronics X400 DAC - sound cutting out over certain volume

Tags: audio

I am using a [Suptronics/Geekworm X400](http://www.raspberrypiwiki.com/index.php/X400_V3.0) DAC with a Pi4.

I have an intermittent issue where the sound will cut out over a certain volume.

After a couple of reboots, the system will work correctly and the volume can get cranked up. After another reboot the issue will reappear. It doesn't matter whether the volume is increased using the hardware knob on in software.

This happens when using both volumio and the the balena-sound project.
I don't know where to start debugging this issue, and would like some advice.